# Populate postgres database with sample data

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, hibernate, populate

I have 3 entities in postgresql database.

```
@Entity
public class dog{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "dog_id")
private Integer id;

private String name;
private int age;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class cat{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "cat_id")
private Integer id;

private String name;
private String sex;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Shelter{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = dog.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "dog_id", columnDefinition = "serial")
private Integer dog_id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = cat.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "cat_id", columnDefinition = "serial")
private Integer cat_id;

private int freeSpace;
}
```

What is the best way to populate database? I need around 1000 test records. I would like to keep the relations between particular values. I have tried writing queries through pgAdmin, but there's no chance to create the relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot you can create a `data.sql` file in the `src/main/resources` folder of your project with the SQL `INSERT` statements you want to use to populate your db. ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

Comment: How do I set up the relations between entities tho? Foreign keys etc.

Comment: Since you're using Hibernate you should be able to set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `create` on startup which will use your annotations to generate the database schema. (ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate)